# Angular: How to use ng-if inside ng-repeat within a table?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looping through the properties of an object called an observation. One of those properties is ImageUrl. The ImageUrl is not important to the user and it's value is a Base64 image...so it's a mile long. I want to show all properties except the ImageUrl property. I'm trying to use ng-if to exclude it, but it's not working. Any tips? This is an old Angular 1 app at my work and I don't have any authority to upgrade it to Angular 2 or any other framework. I just need this ng-if to work or for someone to suggest an alternative that'd work. Thank you. This is my best try and it's not excluding ImageUrl. I can't get the ng-if to exclude anything.

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in properties(obs)">
                <th ng-if="p !== 'ImageUrl'">{{p}}:</th>
                <td ng-if="p !== 'ImageUrl'">{{obs[p]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi .. can you post also your Angular js code ? .. try to use maybe lodash to filter your array ( or if you use ES6 you can o it by vanilla js)

Comment: ng-repeat is generally used to handle cases where the total number of items you want to create elements for is unknown, or prohibitively large. If you are just trying to create a table with one row per property, why not do it explicitly and remove the ng-repeat and ng-if's altogether?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in obs">
    <td ng-if="key !== 'ImageUrl'">{{val}}:</td>
    <td ng-if="key === 'ImageUrl'">{{key}}</td>
</tr>
```

That way 'ImageUrl' will be shown in case of the ImageUrl property, else the value of the property.